# Javascript - toggling div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I want to show only one text first and then onclick show the other one
This is what i have so far.

```
 <div id = "name1">
        <p>Site Comparison</p>
        </div>
        <div id = "name2">
        <p>Time Comparison</p>
        </div>
        <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox"  id="isCheckBox" (change)="yourfunc($event)"/>
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
```

And js:

```
 yourfunc(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById("name1");
      var y = document.getElementById("name2");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }

    if(e.target.checked){  
      this.loadData2();
    } else {
      document.getElementById("name2").style.display = "block";
      this.loadData();
    }
 }
```

Comment: You have not written any code to do something on click. On click of which thing you want to show another one ? Do you mean on click of first text (name1) you want to show second text (name2) ?

Comment: So the first one, should be shown automatically ( f.e name1) and when you click on it the button it shows you the name2 instead, i'll update the code i didnt put all of it

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. Just wrap the if-clause into an event listener:

```
var x = document.getElementById("name1");
var y = document.getElementById("name2");

y.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you sir, i didn't fully post the code. Can you take a look now ?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use Bootstrap, there is already has an option that is called `collapse`.
I can not really explain it to you in an answer but here is a link to a good explanation with some examples: [Bootstrap Collapse](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_collapse.asp)